# Showing that this Markov chain is transient

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have the following birth-death chain, and I want to find the conditions on which the chain is transient:

[image: chain]

To show it is transient, I can just show $\Sigma_{k \geq 1} p_{ii}^{(k)} <\infty$ (here $p_{ii}^{(k)}$ is the probability or returning to i starting from i in k steps. Alternatively, I can also show that that is a non zero probability of never returning to a particular state, say 0. Problem is, I don't know how to show either of these things. Could someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, is $p_{ii}^k$ the probability to return to $i$ at time $k$ for the first time, or just the probability to be in $i$ at time $k$ (including when it's not the first time) ?

Comment: do you know the gamber's ruin / 1 d random walk for $p\in [0,1]$? if so, since the chain has a single communicating class, it suffices to show that given a start at state 1, you do not visit state 0 WP1 for $p\gt \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I think it is the summation of probability including when it's not the first time. We can take the indicator function for renewals, and when we take expectation over this, we get $p_{ii}$

Comment: @user8675309 I have seen random walks, but only those that are symmetric about 0, which made it easy to show positive recurrence etc. I'm not too sure how to prove things if the DTMC has structure as shown above

Comment: none of the typical random walks on the integers are positive recurrent-- they are transient or null recurrent. It's quite hard to find a base for you to build on here.